# SMPS troubleshooting (unable to provide enough current)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

Recently I found one of my SMPSs (a laptop power brick) malfunctioning, what happened is - it provides enough voltage as declared, but it can't sustain at the mentioned current even at short circuit (below the mentioned threshold) it goes up to 1 A and falls and oscillates.

I have checked the output cap (not checked the capacitance yet, as I have to desolder), it's not bulged neither the filter diode at the output is damaged.

The switching FET and diode also seem good (my meter doesn't have enough voltage to make it beep at continuity still it gives some reading).

I am not certain if the optocoupler can cause the error, due to insufficient gain, it is less likely!

Please help me with where should I start looking next.

Comment: A laptop power brick should not be expected to behave like a bench PSU and supply current into a short circuit. It's almost certainly detecting the short and shutting itself down to try to prevent further damage.

Comment: What does it do when you connect to a load that will draw its rated current or a little less?

Comment: Sounds perfectly normal. Get a CV/CC power supply if you need one, not a laptop adapter.

Comment: Unless you are familiar with high voltage and SMPS, do not try. It is not worth your life, that is, dying over. Get a used brick, with somewhat more power delivery. Those bricks are a pain to work with anyway, and it will likely break again soon after you fix it (if you can ) because it has already been cooked and stressed, and you don't know how many other devices have been affected. Also, its continued functioning will depend on you restoring properly its heat-removal mechanisms -- all that stuff you are having to remove to just get to the circuit and devices. Guessing < 10 USD for used.

Comment: sorry for the miscommunication, I have a  digital load I tested through that first. then tested with a very low-value power resistor, which is near shortcircuited, I am aware of the protection features inside SMPSs, sorry for the foolish-looking statement.

Comment: I did also tune the resistance of the power resistors(combination)  to be just above the allowed current.

Comment: @ MicroservicesOnDDD Thank you for your concerns, I really appreciate that. I am taking all the protections and preventive measures to my knowledge, and never working online, and always draining the caps.

Comment: @Transistor I just plugged a real load, a 24 V dc brushed motor, it is doing just like -start and soft fade, frequency is about 1 Hz. seems like a sawtooth with steep rise . I am sorry, can't provide the waveform, yet to have an oscilloscope.

Comment: @ brhans, @ winny, @ MicroservicesOnDDD I don't intend to use it as a benchtop PSU, it is just an exercise.

Comment: Motors have high starting current requirements. A laptop PSU would not be designed to handle that.

Comment: Still, you are expecting CC/CV functionality from it. The inrush current for that motor is larger than the brick is designed for so it's auto-restarting at that ~1 Hz frequency. Completely normal phenomenon.

Comment: I believe that Motor is rated at 1 amps at 24V, anyway, the psu is rated at ~2.5 A at 19V. I am assuming that PWM controller has been broken. Even with pure resistive load in my digiload, it was doing that same thing, I am also agreeing with your point that, there might be a limitation with inductive loads in that case it shouldn't be satisfying the previous case. I think I have to hold on till I get the scope.